# avoiding spuriously empty apparatus and missing \ledrightnotes in reledmac

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

I am using `reledmac` for a critical edition. My critical apparatus has a *lot* of text in it and many individual entries. This seems to cause `reledmac` to give up printing the apparatus sometimes, just leaving it blank where in fact there should be many entries.

Is there a way to force `reledmac` to print every "footnote" (i.e., every entry of my critical apparatus) even if that means blank space on the page (i.e., just a few lines of the main text so as to make sure that the whole apparatus for that page fits)?

Also, and possibly related to this, I have been using `\ledrightnote`s to print the folio numbers of a manuscript and the page numbers of a prior edition. This works up to a point in my document and then suddenly stops; thereafter, no more such side notes are printed. This cessation of side notes happens to correspond to the *first page that is missing its entire apparatus*, which makes me think there may be a causal relationship between the problems.

Here is part of the log for the compilation I just ran (in the output, the first page with missing `reledmac` footnotes/apparatus is p.16, and after that no more sidenotes appear, though the line numbers continue to appear and the apparatus *is* printed on the remaining pages):

```
Overfull \vbox (12.60089pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[9]
Overfull \vbox (4.67494pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[10]

Package reledmac Warning: 2 sidenotes on line 392 p. 11 on input line 1653.


Overfull \vbox (5.16893pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[11] [12]
Overfull \vbox (13.963pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[13]
Overfull \vbox (3.06186pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[14]
Overfull \vbox (10.275pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[15] [16]
Overfull \vbox (6.765pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [17]
Overfull \vbox (9.57304pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[18]
Overfull \hbox (0.99655pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3243--3295
\TU/LinuxLibertineO(1)/m/n/12 φασὶ, καὶ [][] παροξυνόμενον[][] διὰ τὸ στυπτηριῶ
δες· καὶ [][] καλακάνθιον[][] [][] συλ-

Overfull \hbox (0.99655pt too wide) detected at line 3295
[]\TU/LinuxLibertineO(1)/m/n/12 φασὶ, καὶ [][] παροξυνόμενον[][] διὰ τὸ στυπτηρ
ιῶδες· καὶ [][] καλακάνθιον[][] [][] συλ-

Overfull \vbox (13.57307pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
[19]
reledmac reminder:
 The number of the footnotes in this section has changed since the last run.
 You will need to run LaTeX two more times before the footnote placement
 and line numbering in this section are correct.
```

## Edit: MWE

I have tried to produce a *minimum* example, but doing that I have been unable to reproduce the problem. So instead what I did is I took my whole draft edition, blanked it out with dummy text, and compiled it with `xelatex` (multiple times, as required). This still did result in a blank apparatus on p.12 and then another blank one on p.14, after which no more sidenotes were printed (i.e., on p.15 and after).

Here is [the tex file used to produce this problem](https://gist.github.com/alexandreroberts/aab46df07e4ef5e4255c46019c778448), in hopes that this makes it easier for experts to spot the problem.

## Edit: MWE v2

Here is the [new version](https://gist.github.com/alexandreroberts/a62492b9f597b4a5ebc6ed779ec9688c). (I tried to paste the whole thing into my question, but StackExchange tells me that that is too many characters.)

I've taken out the Greek (and other fonts). I've also taken out the `auxdir={_aux}` option when loading the `reledmac` package.

When I compile this version, the first page with missing footnotes is page 2; note the two blank registers shown with arrows in this screenshot:

[image: two blank registers]

In the TeX code this corresponds roughly to line 375 (though it's hard to give a specific line, since the problem is the lost footnotes on a whole page).

Note also that the sidenotes stop soon after that, with one more on page 3, even though there are many more commands that call sidenotes in the rest of the document (`\BBBBp` and `\Mfol`).

Also, I should emphasize that footnotes do continue appear after page 2 (although again some are missing on pages 6, 8, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 20, and 24). The point is that *no* footnotes should be missing --- or if this behavior is intentional, I would like some way to override it by telling reledmac to print all footnotes no matter what, even if that means having tiny amounts of "main text" on a given page.

## Edit: MWE v3

Based on @cfr's answer, I have made a new MWE from scratch and posted it [here as a gist](https://gist.github.com/alexandreroberts/fe6555c85c2c43bfe47ee949d7def12e). The answer given by @cfr uses a truncated version of the file, but when I ran the full file (with the modifications from that answer), I still got blank apparatus.

In this new version, I deleted all ordinary `\footnote` commands too, in case that was somehow getting in the way. I also avoided loading the `geometry` package at all. I think I have also formatted `\msdata` and `\stopmsdata` commands correctly now.

When I compile it (many times), I find that the apparatus on the very first page (as well as some other pages) is blanked out.

## update: command used to compile

Just in case the problem is somehow with how I am compiling the document, here is the command I use:

```
❯ xelatex main3
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main3.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
```

I then run `xelatex main3` three more times.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: This likely to be hard to debug without an example. I assume you mean the warning  `You will need to run LaTeX two more times`  does not go away if you latex the document two more times?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: yes, that's right, it does not go away no matter how many times I run XeLaTeX. I was hoping an example wouldn't be necessary because that would basically be the whole edition, though maybe I could manage to reproduce it by writing a page with some massive loremipsum apparatus notes. If no one knows an answer to this in the abstract, I'll try to put together such an MWE.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: now I have added a concrete example to my question.

Comment: You shouldn't use local fonts when reporting such problems ("Linux Libertine" etc.). Your example will only run if a user trying to help you also has those fonts, by coincidence; I do not. Could you please produce another mock example without local fonts?

Comment: Also, at which point in your document do things start to go wrong? You pointed to the page numbers (thanks!) but which lines of code are those, approximately? Sometimes a fresh set of eyes can spot an error... I tried to look at the code locally, but didn't know where to start.

Comment: you could add the example  here rather than an external link , but I get `! Package fontspec Error: The font "Menlo" cannot be found.`  and so no output.

Comment: If I comment out Menlo it stops at `! I can't write on file \`_aux/document.1'.`

Comment: If I comment Menlo and don't set the aux to non-default, it compiles, but I don't see the problem you describe e.g. I have footnotes on page 17.

Comment: This still has the `_aux` issue. It would also be easier if the code wasn't obfuscated e.g. `\BBBBp` is not obviously anything to do with creating a note.

Comment: You can reduce this and still show the problem e.g. if I end in the middle of page 4, I *think* that demonstrates the issue (or some of the issues? not sure).

Comment: Note that, as my images show, I **also** checked my answer with your original, longer MWE. So it isn't true my answer relies on the truncated version. I cannot **include** the longer version because I'm subject to the same character limit you are.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that you weren't using the bigger file, only that what is posted uses the truncated version, as you say. In any case, I find the problem still exists in this larger file. I will try to produce a truncated version that still has the problem for better posting/testing.

Comment: Curiously, when I truncate it by deleting the last `\msdata`...`\stopmsdata`, the problem goes away. Maybe this is only a coincidence?

Comment: I'm using the same command (different filename), but I'm explicitly excluding personal configuration i.e. `TEXMFHOME=/d xelatex prawf`. I've got the same LaTeX, but my L3 programming layer is more recent: 2023-10-10. I wouldn't expect that to matter. I'm not surprised deleting `\msdata`, `\stopmsdata` makes a difference. In my testing, the results are hyper-sensitive to very precise differences in how those commands are used. E.g. `\msdata{}aa\somenotemacro{}` will work, but `\msdata{}\somenotemacro{}aa` will fail. I suspect the cat code of the adjacent character matters (sim `\stopmsdata{}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Re. MWE 3

It is not necessary to remove `geometry` if you include the appropriate code in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`, but deleting it is obviously one way of avoiding the problem.

MWE 3 doesn't work because you still have spaces before `\stopmsdata`. You need to remove these. A line break is space. At lines 3330-3331, for example, we see

```
aaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa.
\stopmsdata
```

As I explained below, **this is erroneous and expected to fail**.

You need

```
    aaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa.\stopmsdata
```

with NO space at all. The same is true for the earlier occurrence of `\stopmsdata`.

I tested my changes with your longer example (MWE2) and not only the truncated version I posted here. I also included an image showing pages 24-25, which do not exist in the shortened version.

You should also include the `\AtBeginDocument{}` code even if you don't use `geometry`

If I make **all** these changes to MWE3, then, using `geometry`, I get (I think) all of the expected notes:

[image: mwe 3 pages 1-3]
[image: mwe 3 4-6]
[image: mwe 3 7-9]
[image: mwe 3 10-12]
[image: mwe 3 13-15]
[image: mwe 3 16-18]
[image: mwe 3 19-21]
[image: mwe 3 22-23]

### The source can be found [here](https://0x0.st/HJUs.tex). Note that such links are perishable, but it is too much to post here.

I removed the non-default aux directory option from `reledmac` and reduced the example. Ending in the middle of page 4 is sufficient to demonstrate the loss of both a footnote and side notes. I also replaced some of the obfuscated commands (the ones to do with sidenotes) with more semantically meaningful ones to make debugging a bit easier.

As explained in `reledmac`'s manual (section 3 'Compatibility Warning'), if you use `geometry`, you need to make some adjustments, as detailed in section 7.12.7 on page 53. In particular, you are advised to add

```
\AtBeginDocument{% page 53
  \maxhnotesX{0.8\textheight}%
  \Xmaxhnotes{0.8\textheight}%
}
```

to your preamble.

If I add these lines into my reduced example, the missing footnote and sidenotes are no longer missing.

In addition you cannot have a space between `\msdata` or `\stopmsdata` and the text (section 6.4.1 page 37).

This code is not in my reduced example, but in your longer code, you need, for example

```
\msdata{\sigM \sigA  (\sigA)}aaa’\BBBBp{263} aaa \edsource{aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaa}{\jjjjjj 383.27}
```

It is NOT sufficient to write `\msdata{...}\BBBBp...`. You need the actual text of the section to begin immediately following the argument to `\msdata`. At least, I could not get your full example to work correctly without switching the note to follow the first word.

See also section 19.1.6 page 75 and references for limitations when using `\Xarrangement{paragraph}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1in, right=1.8in, left=1.8in, bottom=1in, foot=.24in]{geometry}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle,hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareAutoPunct{.,}
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{\footnote{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#4#5#3#6}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\AtBeginDocument{% page 53
  \maxhnotesX{0.8\textheight}%
  \Xmaxhnotes{0.8\textheight}%
}

\Xarrangement{paragraph}

\Xnumberonlyfirstinline
\Xnumberonlyfirstintwolines

\newcommandx{\var}[2][1,usedefault]{\Afootnote[#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\explanatory}[2][1,usedefault]{\Bfootnote[#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\sources}[2][1,usedefault]{\Cfootnote[#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\testimonia}[2][1,usedefault]{\Cfootnote[#1]{#2}}
\newcommandx{\trivial}[2][1,usedefault]{\Dfootnote[#1]{#2}} 

\newcommand{\edvar}[2]
   {\edtext{#1}{\var{#2}}}
\newcommand{\edlemvar}[3]
   {\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\var{#3}}}
\newcommand{\edtrivial}[2]
   {#1} 
\newcommand{\edlemtrivial}[3]
   {#1} 
\newcommand{\edsource}[2]
   {\edtext{#1}{\sources{#2}}}
\newcommand{\edlemsource}[3]
     {\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\sources{#3}}}
\newcommand{\edexplain}[2]
   {\edtext{#1}{\explanatory{#2}}}
\newcommand{\edlemexplain}[3]
   {\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\explanatory{#3}}}

\newcommand{\msSiglum}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\sig}[1]{\msSiglum{#1}\unspace\xspace}
\newcommand\sigA{\sig{A}}
\newcommand\sigB{\sig{B}}
\newcommand\sigC{\sig{C}}
\newcommand\sigD{\sig{D}}
\newcommand\sigE{\sig{E}}
\newcommand\sigF{\sig{F}}
\newcommand\sigG{\sig{G}}
\newcommand\sigH{\sig{H}}
\newcommand\sigI{\sig{I}}
\newcommand\sigJ{\sig{J}}
\newcommand\sigK{\sig{K}}
\newcommand\sigL{\sig{L}}
\newcommand\sigM{\sig{M}}
\newcommand\sigN{\sig{N}}
\newcommand\sigO{\sig{O}}
\newcommand\sigP{\sig{P}}
\newcommand\sigQ{\sig{Q}}
\newcommand\sigR{\sig{R}}
\newcommand\sigS{\sig{S}}
\newcommand\sigT{\sig{T}}
\newcommand\sigU{\sig{U}}
\newcommand\sigV{\sig{V}}
\newcommand\sigW{\sig{W}}
\newcommand\sigX{\sig{X}}
\newcommand\sigY{\sig{Y}}
\newcommand\sigZ{\sig{Z}}

\newcommand{\Ms}{\msSiglum{M}\textsuperscript{s}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Mc}{\msSiglum{M}\textsuperscript{c}\xspace}


\newcommand{\ledrightnotebf}[1]{|\ledrightnote{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\BBBBlineend}[1]{\unspace}
\newcommand{\ledrightnoteM}[1]{|\ledrightnote{M #1}}
\newcommand{\ledrightnoteA}[1]{|\ledrightnote{A #1}}

\newcommand{\BBBB}{BBBB\xspace} 

\newcommand\jjjjjj{jjjjjjjj\@\xspace} 
\newcommand\pppppppp{pppppp\xspace}


\newcommand{\emend}[1]{<#1>}
\newcommand{\supplement}[1]{[#1]}
\newcommand{\delete}[1]{\{#1\}}


\newcommand{\authornametrans}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\authorname}[1]{\emph{#1}} 
\newcommand{\bookTitleTrans}[1]{\emph{#1}} 
\newcommand{\bookTitle}[1]{\emph{#1}}


\newcommand{\add}{add.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\attic}{Attice\xspace}
\newcommand{\corr}{corr.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\del}{del.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\om}{om.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\recte}{recte\xspace}
\newcommand{\sic}{sic\xspace}
\newcommand{\suppl}{suppl.\xspace}

\newcommand{\no}[1]{no.~#1} 
\newcommand{\nos}[1]{nos.\ #1} 
\newcommand{\No}[1]{No.~#1} 
\newcommand{\Nos}[1]{Nos.\ #1} 

\newcommand{\aup}[0]{\textsuperscript{a}}
\newcommand{\bup}[0]{\textsuperscript{b}}
\newcommand{\ro}{\textsuperscript{r}\xspace}    
\newcommand{\vo}{\textsuperscript{v}\xspace}    
\newcommand{\rovo}{\mbox{\textsuperscript{r-v}}\xspace} 
\newcommand{\Sup}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}\xspace}

\newcommand{\oneup}{\Sup{1}}
\newcommand{\twoup}{\Sup{2}}
\newcommand{\threeup}{\Sup{3}}
\newcommand{\fourup}{\Sup{4}}
\newcommand{\fiveup}{\Sup{5}}
\newcommand{\sixup}{\Sup{6}}

\xspaceaddexceptions{\ccc \Line \Lines \Linebot \Linesbot \Linestopbot}
\newcommand{\Line}[1]{\mbox{\textsubscript{#1}}}
\newcommand{\Lines}[2]{\mbox{\textsubscript{#1-#2}}} 
\newcommand{\Linebot}[1]{\mbox{\textsubscript{⌂#1}}} 
\newcommand{\Linesbot}[2]{\mbox{\textsubscript{⌂#1-⌂#2}}} 
\newcommand{\Linestopbot}[2]{\mbox{\textsubscript{#1-⌂#2}}} 

\newcommand\aka{a.k.a.\@\xspace}    
\newcommand\bo{b.\@\xspace} 
\newcommand{\ca}{ca.\@\xspace} 
\newcommand\cf{cf.\@\xspace}
\newcommand\Cf{Cf.\@\xspace}
\newcommand\ch{ch.\unspace~}    
\newcommand\Ch{Ch.\unspace~}
\newcommand\chs{chs.\@\xspace}  
\newcommand\Chs{Chs.\@\xspace}
\newcommand\col{col.\@\xspace}  
\newcommand\cols{cols.\@\xspace}    
\newcommand\di{d.\@\xspace} 
\newcommand\ed{ed.\@\xspace} 
\newcommand\Ed{Ed.\@\xspace} 
\newcommand\edtrans{\ed/\trans}
\newcommand\Edtrans{\Ed/\trans}
\newcommand\esp{esp.\@\xspace}
\newcommand\fo{fol.\@\xspace}
\newcommand\fol{fol.\@\xspace}
\newcommand\ff{fols.\@\xspace}  
\newcommand\fols{fols.\@\xspace}    
\newcommand\fl{fl.\@\xspace}    
\newcommand\note{n.\unspace~}   
\newcommand\notes{nn.\@ }       
\newcommand\para{¶}         
\newcommand\paras{¶}
\newcommand\Para{¶}         
\newcommand\Paras{¶}
\newcommand\pa{p.\unspace~}
\newcommand\pp{pp.\@\xspace}    
\newcommand\trans{trans.\@\xspace} 
\newcommand\Trans{Trans.\@\xspace} 
\newcommand\re{r.\@\xspace}     

\begin{document}

\subsection{notes}

\subsection{edition}

\beginnumbering
\autopar

aaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa
aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaa

% No space between \msdata and text
\msdata{\sigM \sigA}aaaa aa aaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa·   
aaaaaaaa, aaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa
\edvar{aaaaa}{\sigA??~: aaaaa M - ????}
aaaaa
aaaaaaaaa.
aaaaaa aaaaaa \authorname{aaaaa} a aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa
aaa aa aaaa aaaaa
\edtrivial{aaaaa}{aaaaa \corr \BBBB}
aaa
aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaaa aaa aaa   
aaa aaaaaa
aaaa aaaaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaaaaa}{\sigA?? \corr \BBBB~: aa’ aaaaaaa \sigM}
aaa aaaaa aaaaaa, aaaaaaaaa,
aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaaaaa aaaaa \authorname{aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa} aaaaaaaaa aaa aa aaaaaa aaaaaa
aaa aaa aa aaaa aaaaaa.
\ledrightnotebf{425}
aaaa aaaaaa \authorname{aaaaaaaaaa} aaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa
aa aaaaaaa aaa,
aaa aa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa.
aaaa aaaaaa
\edlemtrivial{\authorname{aaaaaaa aaa}}{aaaaaaa aaa}{\attic aaaaaaa aaa}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa.
aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa
aaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaa\ledrightnoteM{79v}aaaaaa
\edvar{aaa}{\sigA??~: \om \sigM}
aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaa
\authorname{aaaaaaaaaaaa} aaa \authorname{aaaaaaaa},
aa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa
aaa aa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa.


aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaa
aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa,
aa aaaaaa 
aaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa,
aa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaa.
aaaaa aa
\edvar{aaaaaaaaaaaa}{\sigA??~: aaaaaaaaaaaa \sigM}
aaa
aaaaaa
\edexplain{aaaaaaaaaaaaa}{\cf \pppppppp}·
aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa,
aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa,
aaa
\edtrivial{aa’ aaaaaaaa}{aaaaaaaaaa \sigM}
aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa·
aa aaa aaaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaa}{aaaaaa \sigM}
aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa
aaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa,
aaa aa aaaaa aaa aaaaa·
aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa a aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa·
aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aa aa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa, aaaa aa aaaaa   
aaa aaaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa
(aaaaaaaaa
\edtrivial{aaa aaaaa}{\attic aaa aaaaa}
aa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa),
aaaaaa aaa
\edtrivial{aaa}{aaa \sigM} aaaaa\ledrightnotebf{426}aaaaaa
\edvar{aaaaaaaaa}{aaaaaaaaa \sigA??},
aaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa.
aaaaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaa
aaa’ aaaaa aaa
\edvar{aa}{\om \sigA??} aaaaaa aaaaaaa,
aa aaa aa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa,
\edvar{a}{\sigA??~: a \sigM}
\edvar{aaaaa}{\sigA??~: aaaaa M --- lksjdflkjlksjdflkjsdofijwoeif woijc lkjsdf lkjsdf lkjsdf}
aaaaaa   
aaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaaa}{aa aaaaa M \sigA??},
a
\edvar{aaaa}{aaaa \sigA??; for the accent, see s.v.\ aaaaa}
aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa.


aaa aaa a aaaaa \authorname{aaaaaaaaaaaa} aa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa \ledrightnoteM{80r}
aa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa
aaa     
aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa.
aaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa, aaa aaaa aaa aaaa aaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa, aa
\textquote{\edvar{a}{\om \sigA??}
aaaaa aaaa aaaaa,
a aa aa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaa}.
\footnote{\label{lksjdflkjsdlfkjowiejfoijwef}\Cf below, end of \S 39 at \note \ref{lksjdflkjsdlfkjowiejfoijwef9}, same quotation.}
aaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaa,
aaaaaaa aaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaaaaaa}{aa(aaaaa)aaa \sigM} aaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa    
aaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa, aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa.
aaaaaaaaaaaa \ledrightnotebf{427} aaa aaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa,
aaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa,
aaaaa aaa aaaaa \authorname{aaaaaaaaaa},
aa aaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa, aaaa·
\textquote{aaaaa aa aaaaaaa, aaaaaaa, aaa
\edvar{aaaaa}{aaaaa \sigA??}
aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa,
aaa aa aa aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa
aaa aaa aaaaaa
\edvar{aaaaaaa}{\sigA??~: aaaaaaa \sigM},
aaa
\edvar{aa}{aaa \sigA??}
aaaa aaaaaa,
aaa aa aaaa aaaaaaa
aaaa 
aaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaa aaaaaa,
aaa aaa aaaaaaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaa}{\sigA??~: aaaaa \sigM}·
aaaaaaaa aaa aa
aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaa
\edvar{aaaaaaa}{aaaaaaaa \sigA??~: \sigM seems to have written aaaaaaaa then corrected it by scraping off the final a and converting the a into the left side of a new final a.}
aaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa \edexplain{aaaaaaaa}{To judge from their translation, \BBBB{}’s omission of the close-quotation mark at this point is a typographical error.}.}


aaaa a aaa aaa aaaa
aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa
aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaa,
aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa,
aaaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaa    
aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaaaa,
aa aaaa aaa aaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaaa}{aaaaaaa \sigM},
aaa aaaa aa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaa.
aa aaa aaaa, aaaaa, aaa aaaaa aaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaa aaaa
aaaaaaaa,
aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaa·
aaaa aa aaaaaa \textquote{aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa}, aaaaaaaa aaaaa·    
\ledrightnoteM{80v}
\textquote{aaa aa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa}.



aaaaaa aa aaa aaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa,
aa aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa,
aaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa
aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa.
\textquote{a} aaa \textquote{aaaaa}, aaaa, \textquote{aa aaaaa aaaaaa,
aaa a aaaaa aa aaaaa aaaaaaaa},
aa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaa   
aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa·
aa aaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaaaaaaaa}{aaaaaaaaaaaa \sigA??}
aa aaaaaaa,
\ledrightnotebf{428}
\edlemexplain{aaaa a aaaaa aaa aaaaaa a a aaa aaa aaaaaa
\edvar{a}{M~: \om \sigA??}
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa}{aaaa a aaaaa…aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa}{lkjsdflkjsdlfkj lksjdf lksjd flksjdf lksdjf lksdjf lskdjf lskdfj lskdfj },
\edvar{aaaaaaa}{lkjsdflkjsdlfkj lksjdf lksjd flksjdf lksdjf lksdjf lskdjf lskdfj lskdfj}
aaaaa
\edvar{aa}{aa \BBBB ???}
aaa aaaaaa aaa aa aaa aaaaaa aaaaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaaaaaaaa}{lkjsd flkjsdf lkjsdf lksjdf lksdjf lskdjf lskdjf slkdfj lskdfj sldkf j}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa
\edvar{aaaaaaaaaaaa}{\sigA??? \BBBB~: aaaaaaaaaaaa \sigM},
aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aa
aaaaaaaa.
aaaaaaaa aa aaa a aaaaaaaaaa aaa a aaaaaa aaa aa aaaaaaaa,
aaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaa·
aaa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa   
aaaaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa,
aaa aa aaa aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa.
aaaaaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa,
aaaa aaa aaaaaaaa
\edtrivial{aaaa}{aaaa \sigM}
aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa.


\edlemtrivial{aaaaaaaaa}{aaaaaaaaa}{aaaaaaaaa \sigM}
aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaaa}{aaaaaaa},
aaa aaa aaaaaa a aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa, aaa aaa aaaaa a aaaaaa, aaaa aa aaa aaa aaaaa,   
aa aaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa \{\edvar{aaa}{M \sigA??~: I propose deleting; cf.\ LSJ s.v.\ aaa II.2.}\}
aaaaaa aaa aaaa aaa
aaaaaa aaa’ aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa a aaaaaaaaa.
aaa aaa aaa aaaaaa \textquote{aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa}, aaa \textquote{aa aaaa aaaaaaa aaaa aaaaaaa},
aaa aaa \textquote{aaaaaaaa aa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa},
\edtrivial{aaaaaaaaaaa}{-aa \sigM}
aa aaa’ aa
\edtrivial{aaaaaaaaaaaa}{Above the epsilon the scribe seems to have written aa in smaller letters.}
aaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaa·
aa aa aaaaaaa aaa    
aaaaaa
aaaaaa aaa aaaaaa,
aa aaaa,
aa aaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaaaaa,
aaa \ledrightnoteM{81r} aaaaaaa, aaa aaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaa,
aaa aaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aa aa aaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaaa aaa aa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa,
aa a aaaaaaaaaa \authorname{aaaaaaaaaa} aaaaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa}{-aaaaaaa aaaaa \attic \BBBB}.    


\edlemvar{aaaaa}{aaaaa}{\sigA??~: aaaa (sic) \sigM}
aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaa
\edtrivial{aaaa}{aaaa \sigM} 
aaaaaaa a aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaaa,
aaaa aaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
\ledrightnotebf{429}
aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaa
aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa.
aa aa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaa aa aaaa aaaa aaaaaaaaa,
aa aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa.   


aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa,
aaa
\edtrivial{aaaa}{no accent \sigM}
aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaa
aaaaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa
aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa·
aaa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaa
\edlemvar{\delete{aa}}{aa}{M \sigA??~: seclusi}
aa aaaa
aaaaaaa,
aa aaa aaaaa aa
\edtrivial{aaaa}{no accent \sigM}
aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaa·
a aaa    
aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaa,
\edvar{aaaaaaaaaaaaa}{-aaa \sigA??}
aa
\textquote{aa aaaa aaaaaa, aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa, aaa aa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa},
aaaaaaa aaa aa aa aaaaaaaa a aaaaaaaaaaaaaa \authorname{aaaaaaa}
\edtrivial{aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa}{\attic aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa}.
aaaa aaa aa aaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaa aaaa,
aaaaaa aaaaaaa,
aaa aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaaa,
aaa aa aaa
aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa.


aa aaaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
\edvar{aaaaaaaaa}{\sigA??~: \om \sigM}
aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa,
\edtrivial{aaa’ aa}{aaaaa \sigM} aaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa
aaa aaaaaaa
aaa aaa’ aaaa aaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaaaaaaaaa
\ledrightnotebf{430}
aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aa aaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa
aaa aaaaaaaa
aaaa\ledrightnoteM{81v}aaaaa,
aa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa,
aaa aa aaaaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaa.

aaaa aaa aaa aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa a aaaaa \authorname{aaaaaaaaaaaa},
aa aaa †aaaa aaaaaaa aaa \edvar{aaaaaaaaaaaa}{codd.~: perhaps read -aaaaaaa}
aaaaaaaa aaa aaaa,
aa
\edvar{aaaaa aaaa}{aaaaaaaaa \sigA??}
aaaa·
\textquote{aaaaaa, aaaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaa.
\edvar{aa aaaa}{my emendation, based on the quotation of this line that immediately follows below~: aaaa aaa M perhaps meaning aaaa aaa~: aa aa aaa \sigA??}
\edvar{aaaaaaaaaaaaaa}{my emendation based on quotation below~: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa M \sigA??}
\edvar{aaaaa}{aaaaa \sigA??}
aaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaa}·
aa’ aa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaaaa
aaa aaa aaa aaaaaa aa \textquote{\emend{aaaaaa,} aaaaaaaa, aaaaaaa aaaaa}
aaaaaaaaaaa aa’ aaaaa aaaaaaaa aa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaaa aaa aaaaa·
aa aaa \textquote{aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa}, aaa aaaa aaaaaa
aaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaaa aaa aaa aaaa aaaaaa·
aaa aaa aaa aaaaaa
\textquote{aaaaaaaaaaaaaa},
aaaaaaaaa aaa aaa aaaaa aaa aaa aaa’ aaaa aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaa aaaaaa aaa.
aaa aaaaaaaa aa \textquote{aa aaaa} aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa,
aaa aaaa aa
aaa
\edvar{aa}{\sigA??~: \om \sigM} 
aaaaaa aaaaaa aaa,
a aa aaa aaaa,
aaa’ aa aaaa aaaa
aa aaaa aa aaa
aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa.    
aaa aaa aaa aaaaaa \textquote{aaaaaaaaaaaaaa},
aaaaa aaaaaaaaa,
aa aaaa aaa aaa’ aaaa
aaa
\edvar{aaaa}{\sigA??~: aaaa \sigM}
aaa\emend{a} aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa·
aaaa aaa aaa
aaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaa,
aa aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa a aaaaaaaaaaaaaa.


aaa aa aaaaaaa aaaaa, aaa’ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaa aa aaaa
\edtrivial{aaaa}{no accent \sigM}
aaaaa
\edexplain{aaa aaaa}{the scribe drew a paragraphos in the margin here},
aaa aaa aaaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa.
\edtrivial{aaaa}{aaaa a}    
\ledrightnotebf{431}
aaa \textquote{aaaaaa aaaaaaaa}
aaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa
aa aaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa,
aaa aaa, aa aaaaa a \authorname{aaaaaaaaaa}, \textquote{aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa
aaaa a aaaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaaa}. aaa aaaaa·
\textquote{aaaa aaa aaa aaaaaa},
aaaa,
\textquote{aaa aaaaaaaa \edexplain{aaaaaaa}{scribe or later hand added a cross in the margin here},
aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa·
aa aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
\edtrivial{aaa}{aaa \sigM}
aaaaaaaaa,
aaa
\edtrivial{aaa}{no accent \sigM}
aaaaa
aaaaaa a aaa aaaaa aaa aaaaaa    
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa,
aaa aa aa aaaaaaaa aaa aaaaaa aaa aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa}.

aaa aaa aaaaaa \textquote{aaaaaa aaaaaaaa}, aaa aaaa aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa.
aaa
\ledrightnoteM{82r}
aa aa 
aaaaaaaaa \textquote{aaaaaaa aaaaa}, aaa aa’ aa
aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaa.
aaa aaa aaaaaaaaa aa’ aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa·
\edtrivial{aaa’ aaaa}{aaaaaaa \sigM}
aaa aaaaa aaaaaaa,
aaaaaaaaa aa aa’ aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa.    
aaa aaaaaa a aaaaaaa aaaaa
\textquote{aa’ aa aaaaaaa a aaaaaaaaaaaa}
aaaaaaaaaaa.
aa aa
\edtrivial{aaaaa}{aaaaa \sigM} aaaaa,
aaa’ aaaaaa,
aaa
\edtrivial{aaa aa}{aaaaa \sigM}
\textquote{aaaaa} aaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaa, aaa aa aaaaa aaaaaa
\edtrivial{aaaaaaaaaaaaa}{aaaa aaaaaaaaa \sigM},
aaaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaa.\stopmsdata % no space between text and \stopmsdata


\endnumbering


\end{document}
```

The result is not exactly pretty because TeX doesn't have hyphenation patterns for a language consisting entirely of strings of 'a's, so sometimes the sidenotes overlap protruding text, but presumably this won't be a problem in your real document.

[There are question marks because I didn't bother to replace cross-references to later labels when reducing the code.]

[image: Footnotes not missing on page 2]

[image: Sidenote on page 4 is no longer AWOL (Absent Without Leave)]

Here are the last two pages of your longer example, just to demonstrate the changes do make the notes behave,

[image: last two pages of modified longer example showing better behaved notes of various kinds]

Note that you should check the order in which you are loading packages. `hyperref` should be loaded after anything you don't know should be loaded later.

Comment: Thank you for trying that, but puzzlingly I find that with the longer version, I still get the blanked-out apparatus on various pages.

Comment: @AlexRoberts Did you make the `\msdata` and `\stopmsdata` changes, too? Without those, I still see the problem. But with those, your original longer version compiles fine. At least, it looks fine to me - if I should be looking for something not shown in the images above, let me know. That is, pages 24-25 above look OK to me - the footnotes and sidenotes seem to be correct. But you **do** have to make **all** the changes, including switching word and note order where necessary. If I have `\BBBBp{263}aaa’`, for example, or end the line, rather than `aaa’\BBBBp{263}`, stuff disappears still.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't made the \stopmsdata change correctly, but now I think I have (I edited the [v3 gist](https://gist.github.com/alexandreroberts/fe6555c85c2c43bfe47ee949d7def12e) directly, so now it should be right). In this new form, it still doesn't work for me (problem is already on p.1).

Comment: @AlexRoberts Please see above. You can see the output I get for MWE 3. You need to include **all** the changes, whether you use `geometry` or not. In fact, I think you may need `geometry` for A4, but I didn't check this thoroughly. At any rate, I used `geometry`. I also did straight run-ons to `\msdata` and `\stopmsdata` without even commented line breaks. Is the output I show the output you're getting? Because, as far as I can tell, nothing is missing.

Comment: could you please post the exact code that produced that output, please (maybe as a gist)? Because when I check the code that I posted as [MWE 3](https://gist.github.com/alexandreroberts/fe6555c85c2c43bfe47ee949d7def12e), I do not see the `\stopmsdata` error that you describe in your updated answer. Or if you do see where the error is, could you point to it, please? Sorry for the back and forth, it would be a lot easier if we could just post the whole documents onto SE. The results you are getting look great, but they are not the results that I am getting.

Comment: OK, I finally managed to get it to work, [using a file I'll call MWE 5](https://gist.github.com/alexandreroberts/e7d3c78fbed3f69e4d606322e64872db) that I think is very close to what @cfr used in the modified version of MWE 3. Unfortunately, when I make the same modifications, it does not work on my real edition file. Other than using real text instead of dummy text, the main difference is that the edition uses Greek characters/fonts, so I suspect the problem might lie with them. I will have to keep fiddling, but the question as I posed it here has been answered, and the answer is a big help!

Comment: @AlexRoberts Not familiar with gists, sorry, but this is my go-to way of sharing large amounts of plain text: https://0x0.st/HJUs.tex. [The links are perishable, but I guess that doesn't matter in this case.]

Comment: Thank you for the HJUs.tex file. It worked for me, so I will use that as a basis for trying to figure out how to make the version with Greek text work.

Comment: @AlexRoberts Good luck. `reledmac` is decidedly picky!

Comment: Thank you, yes, that I have certainly learned from this question-and-answer. I have managed to fix the problem (for now) in my Greek document, by changing the Greek font used and eliminating some "familiar footnotes" (as the `reledmac` documentation calls them, i.e., `\footnote` commands) appearing on pages that had the problem. I'm not sure which change was the one that made it work because I wasn't debugging systematically, but now I know that I have to tread very lightly with this package!

Comment: @AlexRoberts Good. Some of the details are in the documentation, but it wasn't always clear to me exactly what they meant in terms of implementing them. Glad you got it working, anyway.